# Are cookies set even if http message fails?

Tags: http, servlets, cookies

Suppose I have a Servlet that generate a very big PDF file and send the PDF to client, with all the needed Response-Headers (such as Content-Disposition). That servlet also send a Set-Cookie Response-Header.

In the html page, there is an  with the src attribute pointing to that Servlet, to display the pdf in the page.

If, during the stream, for some reason the connection is closed, so that the  just received part of the pdf, is the Cookie set anyway?

More generally: if a browser receive an HTTP message that is truncated (connection lost, or some other reasons), are the Set-Cookie Response-Header eventually received however managed by the browser?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: because I don't know if this is a browser-dependent behaviour. I can do a test for Chrome in Windows 10 - for example - but I wouldn't know if the same still holds for Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7, or Safari on iPad, ecc. I wuold like to know if there is some RFC that indicates the expected behaviour

Comment: I guess that would depend on browser and you can't really guarantee the behaviour. See http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#field.limits for example.